# Many To Many Relationship class design

Tags: c#, vb.net, class, oop

How to handle the following scenario.

I have a `Product` Class Which has `List<Orders>` and `Order` Class which has `List<Products>`.

Is it good to have the above structure or it will create any problem in future.
If its causing the problem, then is there any other way to implement it...

Comment: In combination with any ORM (Entity framework, NHibernate,...)?

Comment: Why would a `Product` need to know the `Order`s that include it?

Comment: In my opinion the `Product` shouldn't have `List<Orders>` property.

Comment: Because I need to get orders for the particular product for any given search condition like Year, Month,Date and between dates..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need a link from `Product` to `Order` because if you want to find out if a particular product has been ordered in the past, then you can search the products associated with each order using the ID of the product. The link from `Order` to `Product` makes sense because this way you can see what products make up the order.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that having `List<Order>` in `Product` class can do much more bad than good. One product can be - in  dependency of size of your project - in thousands of orders.

In that case, even when you simply want to create a list of products, you will have to create thousands of instances of `Order` in it - a completely useless data.

Instead, you can easily take all orders containing the product with :

```
List<Order> _Orders = AllOrders.Where(_Order => _Order.ProductIds.Contains(YourProductId));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could uncouple the Order and Product types by using a tuple to link a Product with an Order.

Remove `List<Order>` from `Product` and `List<Product>` from `Order` and create a third class that contains a `List<Tuple <Order, Product>>`.